# How to create new line in react table column with lots of data

Tags: reactjs

I am using react table. I am calling a method on API (.NET), which concatenates some fields and now I need to display this concatenated field in react table column.

From API I tried to  put `/n` in the column so that it renders a new line on UI (inside react table). But no luck. Example: I need to display

> This field is calculated by adding two numbers 10 and 20. Since the
>   result is greater than 15 you cannot perform this operation.

In the displayed text, what I want is "Since" should start in a new line in react table.

I tried to put `{'\n'}` before "Since" but it did not work. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code, and the full names of any libraries/frameworks you're using?

Answer (score 6):

> The '\n' escape character does not work in HTML. You have to work with
>   other HTML solutions like using `<br>` or divs to get a multiline
>   implementation working.

You solve this quite easily. when getting the string append a special char like the comma (,) or some other char that you are sure would not be used in your original text.

Then get that string to a js variable in your react app.

```
let multiLineString = "This field is calculated by adding two numbers 10 and 20. , Since the result is greater than 15 you cannot perform this operation";
let lines = multiLineString.split(',')
let linesHTML  = lines.map((line)=><div>{line}</div>);
```

now render this variable anywhere you want, you will get a multi line string implementation.

Of course the better approach would be to get a json array of values from the back end.